# Cross browser testing strategy on Mac OS?

Tags: testing

I'm working on a Mac environment. Years ago I had four different "*Parallels*" installations to be able to test websites on four different IE versions. That worked for a while – but it is a bit crazy to have four different virtual PCs just for testing on four different browsers.

I am also aware of the application "*Virtual PC 7*" and "*VirtualBox*" and have tried to run Windows XP via "*Boot Camp*" –– but the overhead of these approaches is just a bit too much.

On the other hand I have tried some online services. Some seem to be promissing, but costy – and I seriously don't want to pay $20-$50 per month just for testing 1 or 2 websites per month.

There is of course also the free/trial versions – but… The free version of [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) won't have IE listed at all, [browsera](http://www.browsera.com/)'s free version won't show hi-res screenshots, [multibrowserviewer](http://www.multibrowserviewer.com/) is PC only, and a.f.a.i.k. [crossbrowsertesting](https://crossbrowsertesting.com/freetrial)'s free 60 minutes are for one week only. The free tool [netrenderer](http://netrenderer.com/) only brings up an error message.

Before I go any further, I would like to ask: does anybody have a recommendable light weight low cost cross browser testing strategy for Mac OS? Any tips / pointers appreciated.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the title of the duplicate question. It covers lots of testing options.

Comment: Thank you for pointing to that page – although I fear I've tried almost all options listed. I'll check again answer by answer and hope I find one working option...